# jquery Add and Remove Classes?

Tags: jquery

I need a script that adds a 2 to the end of a class in a div with the id .sideboxtopleft on clicking of a link with the id of posts.

```
<script>
    $(".posts").click(function () {
      if ($('.sideboxtopleft').is('#sideboxtopleft2')) {
          $('.sideboxtopleft').removeClass('2');
      }
      else{
          $('.sideboxtopleft').addClass('2');
      }
    });
</script>

<div id="sideboxtopleft" class="sideboxtopleft">
<a href="#post" id="posts"><h3>RECENT POSTS <div id="arrow" class="arrow"></div></h3></a>
</div>
<div id="sideboxtopright" class="sideboxtopright">
<a href="#comments" id="comments"><h3>RECENT COMMENTS <div id="arrow" class="arrow2"></div></h3></a>
</div>
```

However it doesn't seem to want to work properly. Any help?

Comment: You do realize that the class 2 (CSS ".2") has nothing to do with the ID sideboxtopleft2 (CSS "#sideboxtopleft2"), right? Perhaps you just mean to use the selector: "#sideboxtopleft.2" -- also, avoid using the same class and ID names unless there is a *very good* reason to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like this:

```
$(".posts").click(function () {
  $('.sideboxtopleft, .sideboxtopleft2').toggleClass('sideboxtopleft sideboxtopleft2');
});
```

[All of the class methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) add, remove, or toggle entire classes, they don't append/remove part of a class name.  Though the above code works, it isn't the most ideal solution, a multi-class selector in CSS is probably a better approach, like this:

```
.sideboxtopleft { color: black; }
.sideboxtopleft.on { color: red; }
```

Then you could just toggle the `on` class, like this:

```
$(".posts").click(function () {
  $('.sideboxtopleft').toggleClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a new class to tag?

```
<div id='foo' class='sideboxtopleft two'>
```